# Dynamic query where clause check

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my `MySQL` procedure

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `awaredb2`.`GetAlertList`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`aware`@`%` PROCEDURE `GetAlertList`(IN deviceIds VARCHAR(200), IN appIds VARCHAR(30000))
BEGIN


        SET @QUERY = '  SELECT P.policy_id AS PolicyId,
                        P.name AS PolicyName,
                        (MAX(A.alert_create_date)) AS AlertCreateDate, ';

        IF deviceIds != ''
        THEN
            SET @QUERY = CONCAT(@QUERY, '   SUM(AR.penalty) AS Penalty, ');
        ELSE
            SET @QUERY = CONCAT(@QUERY, '   '''' AS Penalty, ');
        END IF;

        SET @QUERY = CONCAT(@QUERY,'    A.device_id AS DeviceId
                    FROM alert A
                        JOIN alert_rule AR ON AR.alert_id = A.id
                        JOIN policy P ON P.id = A.policy_id 
                        JOIN device D ON D.id = A.device_id
                    WHERE P.name != '''' ');

        IF deviceIds != ''
        THEN
            SET @QUERY = CONCAT(@QUERY, ' AND A.device_id IN(', deviceIds, ') ');
        END IF;
        -- 
        IF appIds != ''
        THEN
            SET @QUERY = CONCAT(@QUERY, ' AND A.app_id IN(', appIds, ') ');
        END IF;


        SET @QUERY = CONCAT(@QUERY, '   GROUP BY P.name
                        ORDER BY AlertCreateDate DESC ');
        PREPARE stmt FROM @QUERY;
        EXECUTE stmt;
        SELECT @QUERY;
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

This procedures accepts two parameters. If parameter value is not empty, that value would be used in order to prepare sql statement and execute in the end.

Now I am asked to remove first default condition `P.name != ''`. If I remove this condition every time I will have to check other two parameters are present or not. If present then add where clause. If both are present then add `AND` before second check else add it after where clause.

Later there could be more than two parameters for this procedure. So what is the best way to manage this dynamic query with `WHERE` and `AND`?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is just to keep a `WHERE 1=1` in your query. The optimizer will get rid of it and all you have to do is add `AND ...` blocks.

See also http://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/optimizer-primary-optimizations.html , section 8.2.1.2:

> A transformation takes place for conditions that are always true, for example:
>
> ```
> WHERE 0=0 AND column1='y'
> ```
>
> In this case, the first condition is removed, leaving
>
> ```
> WHERE column1='y'
> ```

Comment: will this check affect procedure performance if there are millions of records?